# Trigger load on autocomplete suggestion selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an autocomplete form that gives a suggestion for something the user may be looking for for example if I were to type "ca" it would give a suggestion for "car", "cat", "canon" and so on. Right now I can either have the data change as I'm typing (but that takes away from having the autocomplete) using

```
.on('input', function() {
});
```

or on change but that requires the user  to either click enter or click outside of the text box.

```
.on('change', function() {
});
```

Is there a way to have the data load when the user selects the autocomplete suggestion rather than clicking outside the box or while typing? I've looked everywhere and can't find a thing on this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found the solution, jQuery has an event listener specifically for this action. I'll link the doc where I found this out below.

```
.on('autocompleteselect', function() {
});
```

https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select